# Rails: Run a function that will generate a date and run another function at that date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, time, rubygems

I am looking for a way to make it so that when you run a function it will generate a random date between two defined dates, that will be stored somewhere, so that somehow the other function at that date could be run.

In short I need something that will execute a function at a defined date.

Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, good old `rand` should solve the problem:

```
require 'date'
first = Date.today
second = Date.parse '2018-08-08'
random = first + rand((second-first).to_i+1)
```

Some reference: `random(i)` will generate a random integer in `[0..i-1]` range (including first and last value). And `Date + Integer` gives new `Date`, given amount of days in future. `Date - Date` gives difference between `Dates` in days.

The second question is how do you run the task on specific date. Well, given you have many dates scheduled ahead (and not just one), it would be a good decision to use [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. Just check every day what tasks are due and run them:

```
# config/schedule.rb
every 1.day do
  runner "Task.perform"
end

# app/models/task.rb
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.perform
    self.where(date: Date.today).each do |task|
      # do what is needed to be done
    end
  end
end
```

So you `schedule` the Task by just saving it to the database: `Task.create(date: ...)`, and then wait for `Task.perform` to perform it on the due date.

Comment: And how would I have a method run on that date?

Comment: I've updated my answer with one of possible solutions.